# How to add properties to the WEB.XML file using Grails WebXmlConfig Plugin?

Tags: grails, web.xml, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using the [WebXmlConfig Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) of Grails. I use Version 1.4.1 of the plugin. I did:

```
grails create-web-xml-config
```

to generate the grails-app/conf/WebXmlConfig.groovy file. When I try to add a simple property like:

```
sessionConfig.sessionTimeout = 30
```

I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <session-config> element is limited to 1 occurrence
at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetSessionConfig.begin(WebRuleSet.java:769)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1890)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1259)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I do grails install-templates and delete the session timeout from the generated web.xml file then it works. How do I configure WebXmlConfig.groovy without modifying the original web.xml?

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I use Version 1.4.1 of the plugin.

Comment: Due to [this JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBXML-9). Have a look at the workaround and Burt's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use *grails install-templates* and modify the default web.xml file, as a workaround?

Comment: not working in grails 3.x anymore. Spring Boot is encouraged there.